# value from html to ts

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

I'm new to Angular and need help please.

I have two components..one for index and one for Navigation.

for the index component there are subcomponents, which is changed by a value of a variable productDivision..so if productDivision = 1, the sub-component (A) will be shown in the index and if the productDivision = 2, the subcomponent 2 will be shown instead of 1.

so what I need is ... if I click an element on the navbar, i want the value of the product division to change..to display the different sub-component in the index here is my code.
so how can I take the new value of productDivision  variable from HTML and assign it to ts as a new value of the variable

navbar component: html:

```
<nav id="nav-icons">
    <a class="nav-icon-home" (click)="prodProvision === null; detectProductDivision() " routerLink="/">
      <span class="nav-icon"></span><br />
      Telefon
    </a>
    <a class="nav-icon-mobile" (click)="prodProvision === 1 ;detectProductDivision()" routerLink="/" >
      <span class="nav-icon"></span><br />
      Mobil
    </a>

    <a class="nav-icon-phone" (click)="prodProvision === 2; detectProductDivision()" routerLink="/">
      <span class="nav-icon"></span><br />
      Fax
    </a>
```

navbar.ts

```
  import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navbar',
      templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
    })
    export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
       public productDivision: number;
         public prodProvision;
        @Output() public navbarEmitter = new EventEmitter();
      constructor() { }
        detectProductDivision() {
            this.navbarEmitter.emit(this.prodProvision);
        }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Since you don't specify how the two components index and navbar are related, it's hard to give you a good answer. One of the options here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction is the correct answer, but without knowing more it's impossible to make a recommendation

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if I understood correctly, but you could pass the value through the click function:

```
(click)="myClickFunction(valueThatIwantToPass)"
```

Please if this does not solve your question, expand your question so I can provide you with a better answer, thanks!